# An Algorithm for converting vectors into bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

[image]There ids lots of program and algorithm for converting from bitmap into vector, but I want a simple algorithm to convert a **polygon** that determind with it's **Points** into a **bitmap** or mapping it on a **grid**, in C#.

I'm sure there is lot's of such algorithms, but I couldn't find any; and I will be appreciate for your help.

The above image is a sample of what I want. Input is the Red Polygon and the grid, and the output will be the violet cells.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of creating a bitmap of the appropriate size, and then using `Graphics.DrawLine()` or `Graphics.DrawLines()`?

Comment: I edited the Question:
I add an image to show a sample of what I want.
Input is the Red Polygon and the grid, and the output will be the violet cells.

Comment: Ok so that's a filled polygon which you can draw using [`Graphics.FillPolygon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon.aspx)

Comment: Not exactly. I want just violet cells. Fill algorithm, fills all the polygon; even the cut cells. But I don’t want them.

Comment: Generally, this is called "Rasterization" and is one of the basic algorithms of computer graphics.  Typically you identify a single geometric point to represent each pixel to determine inside/outside.  (This is necessary for consistency, else two adjoining filled polygons would leave a gap between them.)  You seem to want complete containment of the pixel, is that correct?  Do you understand that your request is non-standard for polygon fill?  Is there a reason you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty easy to compute the lines which are tangent to horizontal or vertical axis. so your problem is actually dealing with diagonal lines. you can apply bresenham line algorithm ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)) only on diagonal lines and do the "inverse"

Comment: thanks for your help. But I don't want to map it's border into bitmap. as you can see in the image, I want just inner squares. So "inversing" can't help me either. Because it return the outer squares too; but I dont want them.

Comment: is your shape always closed? if you can get the outer squares, you can get the inner squares using flood fill